# Static file issues with Heroku and Django

Tags: django, heroku

My site was working fine, but then I started having problems with images I was uploading to Heroku.  I was using whitenoise with Django but decided to move my image store and static files to AWS.  I was following along with this tutorial, and was able to get the files in my static folder up to S3.

But now I'm having problems when trying to deploy to Heroku.

Note I have a `static` folder inside of my app folder, inside of root.

Getting this error when pushing--which includes a collectstatic

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/build_f05a3a5f9e4b6ad44dfdf0b62dd16e9e/static'`

I'm pretty sure that it is a temporary storage area for Heroku (?) but i'm guessing that /static shouldn't be on the end.

I'll copy my relevant settings.py variables here:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'dealmazing.storage_backends.MediaStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

#This will make sure that the file URL does not have unnecessary parameters like your access key.
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = config('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = config('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = config('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}
AWS_LOCATION = 'static'

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'

#media storage settings
MEDIA_URL = STATIC_URL + 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

and here is full traceback in case it is needed:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
remote:            self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
remote:            self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
remote:            output = self.handle(*args, **options)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 189, in handle
remote:            collected = self.collect()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 105, in collect
remote:            for path, storage in finder.list(self.ignore_patterns):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 125, in list
remote:            for path in utils.get_files(storage, ignore_patterns):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/utils.py", line 28, in get_files
remote:            directories, files = storage.listdir(location)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 313, in listdir
remote:            for entry in os.listdir(path):
remote:        FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/build_f05a3a5f9e4b6ad44dfdf0b62dd16e9e/static'
remote:
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote:
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the issue is that your `static` directory is empty so git doesn't track it, so when Heroku tries to build your project the directory doesn't exist and you get that error.

If you add an empty file called `.keep` in the `static` directory and add it to git then you can work around this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the comment--much appreciated.  I think there may have been a conflict with Whitenoise--so i removed that and did what you recommended and all is good.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: my static dir is not empty any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

For others and the future me: https://github.com/not-kennethreitz/flango/issues/3 ;)

```
STATIC_TMP = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

os.makedirs(STATIC_TMP, exist_ok=True)
os.makedirs(STATIC_ROOT, exist_ok=True)
```